# Texts are blurry when I migrated Android Studio to a higher resolution display

Tags: android, android-studio, resolution, retina-display

is there any way I can change the resolution of Android Studio? recently I migrate my Android Studio from rMBP 13' to rMBP 15' and the text is blurry. I tried to change its resolution hoping to fix it but found no way to do. do you guys met with this before?
[image]

Comment: If you're not running Apple's implementation of Java 1.6 on your new machine, that could be the problem. Oracle's implementations of Java on MacOS have poor font rendering.

Comment: thanks @Scott Barta. but I use Java 1.7 ...

Comment: You can use Java 1.7 to compile, but you'll get better rendering if you use 1.6 to run Android Studio itself. The compile JDK you set in Android Studio's Project Structure dialog; the run JRE you set in the applications Info.plist file, if I'm not mistaken (but do a Google search to confirm; there have been SO questions about it)

Comment: thanks @Scott Barta. I just installed JRE 1.6 and it works!!! the rending is great. I also found the official doc here:http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.   at System Requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a known issue with IntelliJ and Android Studio on MacOS that only Apple's JDK does proper subpixel antialiasing in its rendering. If you're using an Oracle JDK, then the rendering is not as good.

Unfortunately, this means that the only Java version with good rendering is 1.6; Oracle picked up MacOS support for JDK 1.7 and 1.8.

The good news is that you don't have to use the same JDK to run Android Studio as what you actually use to build; if you have Apple's JDK 1.6 installed, you can use it to run Android Studio, but you can configure Java 1.7 to build with; the latter you configure via the Project Structure dialog.

You can find the relevant bug in IntelliJ's bug tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117324

Answer (score 1):

This blog post helped solve the issue for me on OS X El Capitan: http://inteist.com/fix-fonts-issue-in-android-studio-with-el-capitan-on-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: install [latest Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (e.g. 1.8.0_92).

As per Oracle, [this bug has been fixed in JDK 8](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8000629).
Fonts and icons look crisp on my MBP after updating from 1.7.0_25 to 1.8.0_92.