# How do i set in android studio the Set JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm getting error in the DESIGN:

Android N requires the IDE to be running with java 1.8 or later

I went to the Project Structure > JDK location changed it from 1.7 to the latest I just downloaded 1.8 changed it to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
But still getting this message.

I tried to google found someone else solution also to Set JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables. But I can't find where to set this variables.

This is the solution but not sure how to do it:

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928580/android-n-requires-the-ide-to-be-running-with-java-1-8-or-later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are set for the operating systems and is not dependent on the Android Studio. You can find the details below for setting JAVA_HOME environment variables based on your OS:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

For JDK_HOME you can follow the same procedure by giving the path to your jdk installation

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use Window. See this [link](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows
Step 1 : First open control panel.
Step 2 : In the top right You can find search box, in that you type environment        and click search.
Step 3 :  In that click EDIT SYSTEM ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES.
step 4 :  System Properties Dialogue box will open, in that advanced tab click environment variables.
Step 5 : Environment dialogue box will open in that system variables click new and set the variable name : JAVA_HOME and variable value :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk x.x.x_xx. In x set your value