# Compiler errors in Android API 24 source code

Tags: android

After downloading and installing the API 24 source code, I am seeing a large number of compiler errors in classes that have changes in API 24.

For example, the AccessibilityService class has hundreds of "Cannot resolve symbol" errors on variables, methods, imports etc.

I have tried deleting and redownloading sources multiple times to no avail. Is this a common occurrence with a new set of sources or did I do something wrong?

Edit:

Here is my app Gradle file, and I am using  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nyelito.dactyl"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.2.2"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile(
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
)
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.0.5'
compile 'com.github.thepacific:adapter:1.0.5'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[Here is a screenshot of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmCIC.png)

Comment: If you change back to API 23, does the hundreds errors still occur ?

Comment: Have you tried running the Gradle sync task?

Comment: @AndrewSun Yes, no change unfortunately.

Comment: @LongRanger Just tried it, yes I still get the errors with API 23

Comment: Would you like to post part of your errors and code and the build.gradle you have?

Comment: @LongRanger Sure, added a screenshot of the issue and my gradle file

Answer (score 0):

When you change `compileSdkVersion`, you also need to change `buildToolsVersion` to something compatible. In this case

```
buildToolsVersion 24.0.2
```

Comment: I think this is necessary, but I am still seeing the errors after making the change as well as the change suggested by @LongRanger below.

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nyelito.dactyl"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ...
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
`

Comment: Does the error still be "AccessibilityService class has hundreds of "Cannot resolve symbol" errors on variables, methods, imports etc."?

Answer (score 0):

@Code-Apprentice is right, you need to change buildToolsVersion with the major version number compatible with your compiled sdk version.

['android-24' requires JDK 1.8 or later to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933651/android-24-requires-jdk-1-8-or-later-to-compile)

https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Also, I found you compiled with API 24, which needs JDK8. Please adds the following in your build.gradle

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```