# Design view abruptly stopped working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio was working great, when the design view stopped working abruptly. By design view I mean the preview of the UI one designs in XML. I get a message saying

> Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later. [Install a supported JDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#java8)

I am not sure why this happened without me doing anything. How should I resolve this error?

Comment: Try selecting the SDK level in the preview and setting it to 23 or lower.

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to preview in Android N, you can simply lower the API preview level to API 23 or lower.

Otherwise removing old jdk versions seems to work as well.

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928580/android-n-requires-the-ide-to-be-running-with-java-1-8-or-later) if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But the API preview level was always set to 24. Why did this suddenly become a problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Np, I'm actually not too sure, I'm suspecting it might be due to a bug in one of the Android Studio updates (that I'm getting as well). And it'll be great if you can accept the answer if it helped you out.