# Rendering Issue with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

when I try to use the design view while looking at "activity_main.xml" I have a warning that says "Rendering Problems Android Nougat requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later Install a supported JDK" but I have the current version of Java on my computer.

Comment: Referring to this post should solve your problem probably:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928580/android-n-requires-the-ide-to-be-running-with-java-1-8-or-later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Nougat requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240533/android-nougat-requires-the-ide-to-be-running-with-java-1-8-or-later)

Answer (score 6):

Its because your compiled sdk versions is lower than that of Android N.

try changing the gradle file to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion 24.0.0 rc1
    ...
}
```

Or you change the preview to API 23

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error raise when your java environment path is set to JDK version which is lower than Android studio required(JDK 1.8 above).

downlaod and install the latest JDK(1.8 and above that). Then change your variable path to JDK 1.8. Also if there is any variables name JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME change them to the path of your JDK installation folder.