# Android Nougat requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later

Tags: android-studio

[image][image]

Inspite of having JDK 8 installed, I'm getting this error. What can the issue be?

Comment: try `$ whereis java` and `$ which java` in terminal to find out where your Java installation is...tbh I'm not quite sure about that location...

Comment: Also, when I click on "Install a supported JDK" I'm getting a broken link.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. Check installed java version, it should be 1.8 or later.

```html
MBP-Vitaliy:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

2. Check java version in Android Studio.
   In Mac OS X: Android Studio -> About Android Studio.
   Where JRE should be 1.8 or later.
3. If you have another, In Mac OS X go to Applications folder find AndroidStudio.app and click Show content, then find in Content folder Info.plist file and change JVM VERSION to 1.8 manually.

```html
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.8</string>
```

4. Restart Android Studio.

Comment: How about for Linux and Windows?

Comment: @Vitaliy 
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.8</string>

Above did the trick.  Mine was 
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.6, 1.7+</string>

Comment: @Suragch see my answer for windows users.

Answer (score 5):

for mac users @Vitaliy Movchan answer works.

for windows users (who has to set JAVA_HOME in their operative system):

- Install the JDK 1.8 and note the destination path, usually C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx
- Right-click My Computer and select Properties.
- Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
- In the tab Advanced click Environment Variables
- Create or modify the variable JAVA_HOME.
- Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.

Answer (score 2):

You can still get the layout rendered during design time in the IDE if you choose Android version 23 (Marshmallow) rather than version 24 (Nougat).

[image]

This isn't a long-term solution, but for most purposes it should be good enough. You can always see the actual Nougat layout by running your app in the Android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Add JVMVersion 1.8*, 1.8+ to info.plist of android studio app and also check for default java version

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, in my system i have installed 3 jdks. 
jdk1.6, jkd1.7, and jdk1.8.
I am working on some projects which requires jdk 1.7 so i can't change JAVA_HOME.

So i have found another solution by tell android studio which JAVA_HOME needs to be used.

So i just edit studio.sh file and added JAVA_HOME variable.

**JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/**

[studio.sh file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6w8u.png)

After Restart android-studio started pointing to jdk 1.8.
Hope this will help.