# How to solve Android Studio rendering problems?

Tags: android-studio, java-8

- Created a new project in Android Studio choosing Android N as the minimum SDK with everything else as default.
- Once created open layout/activity_main.xml

Expected result:

- The layout editor correctly displays the empty activity.

Actual result:

- The following error message is displayed:

> Rendering Problems:
>
> Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later. 
>   Install a supported JDK (links to:
>   https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#java8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have old JDK (Java Development Kit) installed to build apps for Android N. Go to this link (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and install java 1.8 or later.

Comment: i already have the last version of JDK!!!

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35974928/6714194)