# Unable to render design of XML in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, rendering

I have installed java 1.8 and installed Android Studios. After I started a new project (Blank activity), I tried to click on the 'design' tab of the xml file display screen.

However I am hitting this error
[image]

I checked my configuration and saw that I already have my java 1.8 setup in the IDE.

[image]

Any advise on how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928580/android-n-requires-the-ide-to-be-running-with-java-1-8-or-later)

Maybe this answer for Mac in that question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38493792/6714194

Comment: Thanks I wasn't able to find the solution after searching. It works

Answer (score 2):

Try switching the UI render to an older version of Android

[image]