# how to build project for different sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

My current configuration in gradle file is

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

this specification make my project specific to java 1.7.

**My requirement is that i should be able to build my project for different java version like for both java 1.7 and  java 1.8**

PS: like profile building in gradle where we can specify different java version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i had solved it

```
ext.javaVer = project.hasProperty('javaVer') ? project.getProperty('javaVer') : '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = javaVer
targetCompatibility = javaVer
```

while building project

```
gradle build -P javaVer=1.8
```

Comment: More recent `gradle` versions may require the `JavaVersion` enum be used, so instead try: ```gradle
ext.javaVer = project.hasProperty('javaVer') ? JavaVersion.toVersion(project.getProperty('javaVer')) : JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7```

Answer (score 5):

Gradle uses whatever JDK it finds in the PATH or JAVA_HOME. So if you remove sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility it should build the project with the Java version used on the machine where the project runs. Of course, this does mean that you shouldn't have constructs like lambdas in the code or compilation on Java 7 will fail.

You should also be aware that starting with Gradle 5 support for Java 7 will be dropped and it will run only with Java 8 (or newer).

Another way to do it is to specify the JDK at runtime, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

If you want to build for multiple Java versions at the same time, you can use something like this:

```
task compile7(type: JavaCompile) {
   source = fileTree(dir: 'src', include: '**/*.java')
   classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
   sourceCompatibility = 1.7
   targetCompatibility = 1.7
   destinationDir = file('build/java7')
}
task jar7(type: Jar, dependsOn: compile7) {
   from('build/java7')
   archiveName = 'project-JDK7.jar'
   destinationDir = file('build/jars')
}
task compile8(type: JavaCompile) {
   source = fileTree(dir: 'src', include: '**/*.java')
   classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
   sourceCompatibility = 1.8
   targetCompatibility = 1.8
   destinationDir = file('build/java8')
}
task jar8(type: Jar, dependsOn: compile8) {
   from('build/java8')
   archiveName = 'project-JDK8.jar'
   destinationDir = file('build/jars')
}
```

You can call `gradle jar7 jar8` to build jars for both java versions you want. Of course, the code above can be improved to parametrize the operations, like this:

```
ext.javaVer = project.hasProperty('javaVer') ? project.getProperty('javaVer') : '1.7'
task compileJ(type: JavaCompile) {
   source = fileTree(dir: 'src', include: '**/*.java')
   classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
   sourceCompatibility = javaVer
   targetCompatibility = javaVer
   destinationDir = file('build/' + javaVer)
}
task jarJ(type: Jar, dependsOn: compileJ) {
   from('build/' + javaVer)
   archiveName = 'project-' + javaVer + '.jar'
   destinationDir = file('build/jars')
}
```

Using this format you would call `gradle jarJ -P javaVer=1.8` and `gradle jarJ` to build for Java 8 and Java 7.

Comment: Is there anyway through command line   we can pass the java version for building project?

Comment: My requirement is to build one war file at a time. i was looking for some solution like this: i read the variable from command line and assign it's value  to sourceCompability and targetCompability

Comment: If gradle uses the jvm on my machine which is 1.8 then why is it failing to build when my app references methods that are only supported starting with Android N and why do I explicitly have to declare targetCompatibility to 1_8 ?

Comment: You can omit targetCompatibility if it's the same as the sourceCompatibility. I can't say why your build fails without some exception. Also, does it fail because a method from the JKD is missing or from the Android API? Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928580/android-n-requires-the-ide-to-be-running-with-java-1-8-or-later